# Get type of array of class using Java reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

In my android project I want to write a function which should return **type of array of class** as,

```
Class getClassArrayType(String strClassName)
{

//some code

return class;
}
```

if I pass "Task" as a class name to above function it should return `Task[].class`.

How can i do this?

I have read about the reflection but it confused me a lot!

Please Help me.

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/arrays.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont't know if it is optimal, but I do it in following way:

```
Array.newInstance(Class.forName("strClassName"), 0).getClass()
```

More over, *strClassName* must be the fully qualified name of the desired class.

Comment: Good trick. Too bad it creates a useless empty array.

Comment: work like a charm!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the best way, but it works, at least for non-array types

```
String className = "java.lang.String";
String arrayClassName = "[L" + className + ";";
Class<?> arrayClass = Class.forName(arrayClassName);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(getClassArrayType(Test.class.getName()));
    }

    static Class getClassArrayType(String strClassName)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class cls = Class.forName(strClassName);

        Object[] arr = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(cls, 10);
        return arr.getClass();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is basically the same solution as agad, except you create an array of 10 elements instead of 0, and add a useless cast to Object[].